# Entering the UK while undergoing visa application

Tags: visas, uk

I spent 6 months in the UK last year (February to August 2016) under a Tier 2 Skills Transfer visa from the US on a US passport.

I will be starting the Tier 2 General visa process with my US employer to move to our UK office in the next month or so. Currently they are undergoing the labor market test.

I have a close friend's wedding in the UK the first weekend of September and I am wondering if I will be able to enter the country while undergoing a separate visa application. I would enter the country after the 12 month cool down period from my visa last year and would have a return ticket to show them I am entering as a tourist (for now).

Will I likely be allowed in? Will entering the UK complicate my current visa application at all? If everything goes smoothly, I should have visa stamp by the end of September or early October.

Answer (score 3):

For your case, you can enter the UK between the end of your cooling-off period and the conclusion of the RMLT.  Obviously you cannot enter the UK during the application stage because they will have your passport. It's also a violation of [Paragraph 28](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk) to be in the UK during the entry clearance application stage.

Re your wedding visit, if it's between the dates mentioned above, you're ok, but be prepared for a rather warm landing interview.

---

Note: be totally sure you have discussed your travel plans with the Authorising Officer at your T2 sponsor. Preferably in writing.

Note: for others following this thread, the OP is applying for a T2 and not a visitor visa. T2's are subject to cooling-off periods whereas visitor visas have no such restriction.